# Добавление полей к Entity в runtime

Tags: jpa, java

Добрый день.

Как добавить поле к уже зампаленной сущности в рантайме? Например, у нас есть сущность *User*:

```
@Entity
public class User {
public User() {}
    @Id
private Long id;
private String name;

/* геттеры сеттеры*/
}
```

Как можно в рантайме добавить необходимые поля для авторизации (login, password, role и т.д.)?

Вопрос связан с кастомизацией приложения на лету. Можно ли это сделать, используя перезапуск *EntityManagerFactory*? Т.е. сгенерировали новый class, добавили его в classpath, сгенерировали новый persistence.xml, подняли EntityManagerFactory заново.

Или есть более феншуйные способы?

Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если в сущности будет поле типа:

```
Map<String, Field> fields = new HasMap<String, Field>();
```

То в принципе на лету можно залезть через [Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) и добавить новое "поле" к полю `Fields`. Единственное придется как то в маппинге хитро прописывать поле `Fields`

Comment: Вы уверены, что на персистентном уровне произойдет ремаппинг? как в таком случае выполнить запрос по новым полям сущности?

)
вопрос наверно скорее из возможных некостыльных способов. Дает ли JPA динамическую возможность менять сущности?

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется проще будет кастомизированые поля для любых entities реализовать подобным образом:

```
user /* основная таблица */
----
id
name
surname
description

ext_field_def  /* задает дополнительные поля */
-------------
id
name
type /* int, varchar, etc... */
description

user_ext_data  /* значения дополнительных полей для конкретного юзера*/
-------------
user_id       /* user.id */
ext_field_id  /* ext_field_def.id */
ext_field_value /* единственный нюанс с типом этого поля, но это тоже можно обойти */
```

Comment: как вариант решения проблемы сойдет, и даже в большинстве случаев лучше так и сделать, но в моем не подходит =(

Comment: видимо вы владеете какой-то важной информацией, но в тоже время не предоставляете ее общественности, соответственно и сообщество не может вам предложить оптимальный вариант.